# adding new dependency with api 27 cause error

Tags: android, maven

after I update android studio to `3.0.0` then add `api27` I couldnt create new project 
because of dependency error I found that I must update my dependency the first dependency `appcompat-v7:27.0.0` and I insert https://maven.google.com in `build.gradle` and   `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"`to download dependency  but it cause another error could not find method for argument and ask for updating android support repository but it is also updated

[my build.gradle(projre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhiAG.png)}

Comment: Please use , and . in your text. It is difficult to read.

Comment: Try don't update to Android Studio 3.0.0. It has bug when you want to use from Log.i().

Comment: thats not where you put your appcompat dependencies mate. That's why it tells you it doesnt know the method. you cant put it there

Comment: where is the right place for it

Comment: post your gradle, also google() in repositories is enough for maven.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to forward your attention to note

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

You opened wrong `build.gradle` file by mistake. Open your `build.gradle` file from `Module: app`, put your `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"` inside `dependencies` block there.

Delete the line from where you have it now.

Comment: i did that but it was like when i created new projects same errors that say unable to resolve dependency

Answer (score 0):

thanks poss i get that code should  be in `build.gradle (module:app)` 
but that didn't work and caused another error unable to resolve dependency 
then i saw that it use https for downloading dependencies but i only used proxy for http so i add settings for https and done